# SQL Table Design - Same FKs in Parent and Child tables

Tags: sql-server, database-design, foreign-keys, database-performance, sqlperformance

Columns in `Member` table:

```
id           (PK)*
client_id    (FK)
location_id  (FK)
address
etc.
```

Columns in `Member_Vehicle` table:

```
id           (PK)*
member_id    (FK)
mileage
etc.
```

Is it good design to replicate FKs already in the `Member` table into the `Member_Vehicle` table?

So the `New_Member_Vehicle` table will be

```
id           (PK)*
member_id    (FK)
client_id    (FK)
location_id  (FK)
mileage
etc.
```

Most of the processing in our application is around the `Member_Vehicle` table.

My thinking is - If the `Member_Vehicle` table readily has the IDs I need, then I can reduce the number of joins between `Member` and `Member_Vehicle` tables.

Your thoughts on why this

1. **is acceptable**

   or
2. **should not be done**

    

   are much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are considering is called **denormalization** and is generally a bad idea in a transaction processing system unless you have very good reasons to do it proven out by production performance issues, for example.

As a rule of thumb, your transaction processing system tables should be in **third normal form (3NF)** and you should back away from this only when needed.

The disadvantage to denormalization is that you could potentially introduce data anomalies (inconsistencies) if there are bugs in your code.

Don't worry about joining tables.  That is what relational database management systems are meant to do.  Before denormalizing, I would consider other physical database performance tricks, like building a *covering index*.

Answer (score 1):

Can a client appear more than once in the `Member` table? If not, the surrogate key there is superfluous. In fact, I'll bet `member_id` is also a surrogate key. Why would you generate another unique value to stand in for a value that is already unique?

So if you drop the PK from the `Member` table, make `client_id` both the PK and FK and change `member_id` of `Member_Vehicle` to refer to 'client_id', you're problem is solved.